# which algorithm can do a stable in-place binary partition with only O(N) moves?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, partitioning, stable-sort

I'm trying to understand this paper: [Stable minimum space partitioning
in linear time.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.25.5554)

It seems that a critical part of the claim is that

> **Algorithm B** sorts stably a bit-array of size *n* in
>   *O(nlog<sub>2</sub>n)* time and constant extra space, but makes only *O(n)* moves.

However, the paper doesn't describe the algorithm, but only references another paper which I don't have access to.   I can find several ways to do the sort within the time bounds, but I'm having trouble finding one that guarantees O(N) moves without also requiring more than constant space.

What is this Algorithm B? In other words, given

```
boolean Predicate(Item* a);  //returns result of testing *a for some condition
```

is there a function `B(Item* a, size_t N);` which stably sorts *a* using *Predicate* as the sort key with fewer than nlog<sub>2</sub>n calls to Predicate, and performs only O(N) writes to *a*?

Comment: From the "[List of Proof Techniques](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~riesbeck/proofs.html)", Proof by ghost reference:
    Nothing even remotely resembling the cited theorem appears in the reference given.

Comment: Funny link, but not applicable.   The reference is to "Stable in situ sorting and minimum data movement" by J.I. MUNRO, V. RAMAN, et al.   Googling reveals that that pair has also published several papers on related topics, including "Fast stable in-place sorting with O(n) data moves. Algorithmica 16, 151–160."  So I think it is a real technique (at least in theory).  But I still can't find a version that shows that it is actually practical.

Comment: Ah, shucks. Re-reading your question you're right, it's not applicable. It's interesting (and sad) to note, though, how many of those show up in papers and lectures. If I had this list while I was still in uni, it would've been much more entertaining.

Comment: Might be worth asking on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

I'm tempted to say that it isn't possible. Anytime you're computing O(n log n) amount of information but have (1) nowhere to stash it (constant space), and (2) nowhere to immediately use it (O(n) moves), there is something weird going on, possibly involving heavy use of the stack (which may not be included in the space analysis, although it should be).

It might be possible if you store temporary information inside many bits of just one integer, or something squirrelly like that. (So O(1) in practice, but O(log n) in theory.)

Radix sorting wouldn't quite do it because you'd have to call the predicate to create the digits, and if you don't memoize the transitivity of comparison then you'll call it O(n^2) times. (But to memoize it takes O(log n) amortized space per item, I think.)

QED - Proof by lack of imagination :)

Comment: I'm certain it is going to involve some bit-packing, based on what I can glean from the papers on the subject I have read.  I just can't quite figure out how yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I have so far.  A version of [cycle sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_sort) which uses a [bit array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array) to hold the result of the partition tests and calculates the destinations on the fly.  It performs a stable binary partition with N compares, < N swaps, and exactly 2N *bits* of allocated storage.

```
int getDest(int i, BitArray p, int nz)
{   bool b=BitArrayGet(p,i);
    int below = BitArrayCount1sBelow(p,i);  //1s below
    return (b)?(nz+below):i-below;
}

int BinaryCycleSort(Item* a, int n, BitArray p)
{
   int i, numZeros = n-BitArrayCount1sBelow(p,n);
   BitArray final = BitArrayNew(n);
   for (i=0;i<numZeros;i++)
      if (!BitArrayGet(final,i))
      {  int dest= GetDest(i,p,numZeros);
         while (dest!=i)                
         {  SwapItem(a+i,a+dest); 
            BitArraySet(final,dest);
            dest = getDest(dest,p,numZeros);
         }
         BitArraySet(final,dest);
      }
   return numZeros;
}

int BinaryPartition(Item* a, int n, Predicate pPred)
{ 
   int i;
   BitArray p = BitArrayNew(n);
   for (i=0;i<n;i++)
      if (pPred(a+i)) BitArraySet(p,i);
   return BinaryCycleSort(a,n,p);
}
```

using these helpers:

```
typedef uint32_t BitStore;
typedef BitStore* BitArray;
BitArray BitArrayNew(int N); //returns array of N bits, all cleared
void BitArraySet(BitArray ba, int i); //sets ba[i] to 1
bool BitArrayGet(BitArray ba, int i); //returns ba[i]
int BitArrayCount1sBelow(BitArray ba, int i) //counts 1s in ba[0..i)
```

Obviously this is not constant space.  But I think this might be used as a building block to the ultimate goal.  The whole array can be partitioned into N/B blocks using a fixed-size BitArray of B bits.  Is there some way to re-use those same bits while performing a stable merge?

Answer (score -1):

Isn't [RadixSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) ?

> **O(kN)**

Comment: I'd like to see you implement that with constant space overhead. Also, the OP clearly mentions using a predicate, not an integer mapping.

Comment: Sorting on a boolean predicate is essentially a 1-bit radix sort. I know how to make that in-place, or stable, but not both.

Comment: Couldn't you compute the prefix-sum over all elements, this gives you the stable index of every element "after sorting" in linear time (with linear extra memory). then you need just some clever way of swapping elements so you only require to swap each pair just once. i guess that's the hard part but maybe possible in n log n?

Comment: @zerm, actually, once you have the indexes, then implementing the O(N) swapping is easy. Look at my answer - you could implement _getDest(i,..)_ as `return prefixIndex[i];`.   The problem I see is with storing the prefix-sums in constant space.   Even with ideal bit-packing, the storage for 1 million prefix-sums is ~2.4 million bytes.

Comment: @AShelly, yes that's the problem I guess. I've been thinking about not storing the full prefix, however this would degenerate to something like bubblesort. However, I'm not really sure - maybe complexity of, say, bubblesort can be reduced when only binary data is present...mhh..

Comment: @AShelly: I can make it in-place and stable, but at a cost of NlgN execution time.  Rather pretty, actually.  If the goal is to e.g. move all uppercase letters to the front and lowercase letters to the back, start by sorting pairs of letters.  Then to turn two sorted groups of N sorted letters into a group of 2N sorted letters, observe that if the first group ends with p lowercase letters and the second group starts with q uppercase letters, one need only rotate the proper (p+q) letters q spaces to the right (or p spaces to the left).  Cute, eh?