# Arrange array of +ve and -ve number with order intact

Tags: c++, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [which algorithm can do a stable in-place binary partition with only O(N) moves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465399/which-algorithm-can-do-a-stable-in-place-binary-partition-with-only-on-moves)

This is one of interview question in which i got struck

**Question:** 
Given a array of integers both positive and negative and you need to shift positive numbers to one side 
and negative numbers to other side with the order intact.
ex. {-1,5,3,-8,4,-6,9} to {-1,-8,-6,5,3,4,9}. This should be done in O(n) and without additional array .

First i thought by  doing this via quicksort like

**Pseudo code**

Find the element nearest to zero.make it pivot element.then apply one pass of quicksort over the array.this is O(n) .

Alas! but Quick Sort is not stable sort?

After that i came with following solution

**Pseudo code:**

Initially, 
increment current till first +ve number and  decerement end till last -ve number

If current is negative , increment current
If current is positive , swap it with the element at end and decrement current and end both
If current >= end , then break.

Still not getting right answer . Need Suggestion on this

Comment: This isn't a solution, but a note: the complexity constraint (O(n), a.k.a. "linear") is a big hint.  You can't use quicksort because it averages n*log(n) and is quadratic in the worst case.  You actually can't use any algorithm that has similar requirements for comparing elements because all of them will be at least n*log(n) complexity.  You have to sort elements without comparing them all against each other.  [BTW when I say "log" it's log-base-2.]

Comment: I might be wrong but maybe they just wanted to see how you approach the problem rather than get an actual solution? [Radix Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) comes closest, but I don't think there are any implementations that are both in-place _and_ stable at the same time. It would also only be O(n) for arrays of numbers with only single digits. Still pretty good though.

Comment: Related: [which algorithm can do a stable in-place binary partition with only O(N) moves?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465399/which-algorithm-can-do-a-stable-in-place-binary-partition-with-only-on-moves).

Comment: @Jesse: I think that's not just related, it's a dupe.  Or do you see a difference?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Actually, I don't. Marking as a dupe.

Comment: @sharaddixit I'm not sure of your efficiency requirement, but I DO know this can be done with a modified insertion sort. The change would be to compare each element against zero, instead of the previous value.

Comment: @itsols: I don't think an insertion sort can be both in-place *and* stable.

Comment: It is not clear if the interviewer was asking O(n) time or O(n) moves as indicated in the so called duplicate. Since I can no longer answer this question, and the answer doesn't belong in the duplicate, I'll just comment. You should ask the interviewer what the real requirements are. But, there are hacks that fit the parameters of the question but can achieve the goal. Sort of like the O(1) removal of a singly linked list node without a pointer to the previous node. The answer is a hack, but is what the interviewer wants to hear.

Answer (score 0):

std::stable_partition does exactly what you want.

For C++11, do

```
std::stable_partition(
  array.begin(), array.end(),
  [] (int i) { return i < 0; });
```

Comment: Interesting. Do you have any idea what kind of algorithm underlies that method? O(n), in-place, and stable sort on integers sounds tricky

Comment: "Complexity: At most `(last - first) * log(last - first)` swaps, but only linear number of swaps if there is enough extra memory. Exactly `last - first` applications of the predicate."

Comment: ...so n log n in the worst case and not in-place then.

Comment: @nbrooks: It's either `O(n)`, or in-place, but not both.

Comment: @ben well generally if you can't guarantee it to be either at a given time you can't really classify the algorithm as that, but I accept your point on the language note

Comment: @nbrooks: Apparently there are two algorithms, one providing each guarantee.  Which is used depends on whether allocation of a second array of equal size succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

If the result array is different from the source array, you can do it easily in two passes:

```
p = 0;   //current index in result array

For i = 0 to length - 1 :
    If source[i] < 0 then
        result[p] = source[i]
        increment p
    End if
End for

For i = 0 to length - 1 :
    If source[i] >= 0 then
        result[p] = source[i]
        increment p
    End if
End for
```

If you want to do it in-place, it's a bit trickier.  You could try a bubble-type sort, but this is O(n^2):

```
n = 0  // number of negative items found

For i = 0 to length - 1 :
    If array[i] < 0 then
        For j = i - 1 downto n :
            swap array[j+1] and array[j]
        End for

        increment n
    End if
End for
```

Unfortunately I can't think of a solution that is both O(n) and doesn't require the allocation of an additional array.