# Segregate Even and Odd numbers, preserve order, O(1) space， O(N) time complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting

```
Input  = {12, 34, 45, 9, 8, 90, 3} 
Output = {12, 34, 8, 90, 45, 9, 3}
```

Given an array of integer, rearrange all even integer before all odd numbers, but keep their original sequence in array, using O(1) space and O(n) time complexity.

Thought:

```
Algorithm: segregateEvenOdd()
1) Initialize two index variables left and right:  
            left = 0,  right = size -1 
2) Keep incrementing left index until we see an odd number.
3) Keep decrementing right index until we see an even number.
4) If lef < right then swap arr[left] and arr[right]
```

But this can't guarantee the order is the same.

What if I want to use O(1) space to solve this problem?

Comment: Why the java tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [which algorithm can do a stable in-place binary partition with only O(N) moves?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465399/which-algorithm-can-do-a-stable-in-place-binary-partition-with-only-on-moves)

Comment: If you would have a linked list instead of an array it would be easy.

Comment: Where did you get this question from anyway?

Comment: Impossible in O(1) space and linear time.

Comment: @Apollys I can't do it in O(1) space, but I don't know how to prove it can't be done in O(1) space.

Comment: https://github.com/strikersps/Competitive-Programming/tree/master/Other-Programs/Segregate-Even-Odd                                                                             This is the best you can do. Time Complexity: `O(n)` and Space-Complexity: `O(n)`. In this problem, there is a trade-off between preserving the order and space complexity i.e. if you want to preserve the order then space complexity will be `O(n)`. If you don't preserve the order then space complexity is `O(1)`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to store last odd and last even position,

```
1. Initialize both last_odd, last_even to -1;
2. Iterate over array
   - Check if array[i] is odd or even,
   - if diff(last_odd/last_even,i) >= 2 and last_odd/even not equal to 
     -1:
        if (element is odd/even) new index = last_odd/even+1
        - store element value in temp
        - move elements from new_index up to i one to right 
          starting back from i-1 down to new_index.
        - store temp in new_index
        - store last_odd/even as new_index accordingly and add to 
          last_even/odd the diff(which is +1)
   - else store last_odd/even as i accordingly
```

Comment: Even if it is stable can you explain how it is O(N) ?

Comment: That is true. It's not possible to do it in O(N), yes if the structure is list (same but internal move reduced to O(1) insetad of k , but not using arrays. But i was reffering to stability

Comment: @TomaszAndel I was wrong, the problem is this: "move elements from new_index up to i one to right starting back from i-1 down to new_index". This is O(n) and the whole thing is O(n^2).

Comment: Yes that is what i said in prev comment. On Array that move has to be done, with lists its possible to do it in const time, otherwise impossible

Comment: @TomaszAndel Yup it is possible in linked list but the question clearly asks for array solution and demands O(N) solution with stability. O(NlogN) solution is already possible with stability. Why post this solution?

Comment: Yeah, this isn't O(n) complexity.  - move elements from new_index up to i one to right creates more complexity if I understand this solution properly.

Comment: Look he is new, don't be too harsh, I didn't downvote, surely just wanted to help, but this is a bad question to start with, because it seems to have no solution.

Comment: As he clearly didn't know how to keep array stable.. If he know how to keep the order than its very clear that the asked task is impossible to achieve in O(n), all comes from understanding. otherwise no one should post anything here, as no solution exist :)

Comment: I don't mind for down voting, i'm here to discuss not to gather points..

Comment: **Edit Suggestions:** If you are sure that it is impossible to do then you might want to provide a justification for that. Please don't post solutions which are not optimal as they are not helpful anyway. At-least you should try posting solutions which are as closed to optimal as possible.

Comment: Do you know a better solution to preserve the order ?

Comment: Yes. There exist sorting algorithms which are stable as well as in-place (i.e. O(1) space). With slight modification in how they compare elements, I am sure we can get O(NLogN) complexity and O(1) space. There is also a paper reference in the dup in comment which claims O(N) complexity but I haven't checked yet. You can improve your answer accordingly.

Comment: The problem is that you did not read that paper(I did) . So your claims are wrong.. Read it and post here and algorithm i will be glad to see it. Paper is about NlogN for your info not about O(N). Read it firstly before you say anything. Paper operates on "probably" terms for your information.

Comment: Hmm, please read my comment again, I only claimed O(NLogN) for my algorithm. I didn't claim anything for the paper. I suggested you to make changes accordingly meaning you decide what is best possible you can do taking into consideration alternatives available to your solution which is certainly not helpful. If not anything at-least add some information about how your algorithm performs in running time and space.